# How to get collection after ajax query

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, web-services, webforms

There is a server method that generates a collection in ajax query.

```
public static void DeleteExistFile(string name, string groupName)
    {
        List<LoadedTrackInfo> _loadedTracks = new List<LoadedTrackInfo>();
        for (int j = 0; j < files.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (files[j].Name.ToString() != name)
                    {
                        _loadedTracks.Add(new LoadedTrackInfo() { libraryFile = files[j] 
                    }
                }
    }
```

After  ajax query, form will be sent 
I need to get the current collection after it is submitted form
Here

```
public void btnEditContract_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        _loadedTracks
    }
```

Any tips, link or code example would be useful.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of applicaiton is this?  Asp.Net Web Forms or MVC?

See if you have access to HttpContext.Current.Items, if so, store _loadedTracks in the object cache,

HttpContext.Current.Items["key_LoadedTracks"] = _loadedTracks;

and retrieve it in the btnEditContrack_Click

List _loadedTracks = HttpContext.Current.Items["key_LoadedTracks"]

Optionally, you might just be able to give _loadedTracks a higher scope, e.g. a static variable outside of that method.

If you are using asp.net webforms, I would suggest changing how your doing your ajax.  You can create a generic ASHX Handler with the .ashx extension, and you can use JQuery to do an ajax post to that, it's much cleaner and nicer to work with.